# how to disable popup if user already likes my website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I am asking users on button click to like my website page. when user likes page and clicks this button again it asks to like my page again. please help to prevent this.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
        var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
        var page_id = "40796308305"; // coca cola page https://www.facebook.com/cocacola
        var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id=" + page_id + " and uid=" + user_id;

        FB.api('/me/likes/'+page_id, function(response) {
            if (response.data[0]) {
                $("#container_like").show();
            } else {
                $("#container_notlike").show();
            }
        });
    } else {
        // user is not logged in
    }
});
```

I tried this code, but it is not working at all.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can't. Like gating is not allowed. You are not allowed to show different things depending if the user liked your page or not

Comment: @WizKid is correct. You can't get a list of users who have liked your page to avoid scenarios like this one.